# How to run Django views from a script?

Tags: django

I am writing a Django management command that visits a few pages, logged in as a superuser, and saves the results to a set of `.html` files.

Right now I'm just using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and running the command with the development server running. Is there an easy way to generate the HTML from a view response so I do without actual HTTP requests?

I could create a request object from scratch but that seems like more overhead than the current solution.  I was hoping for something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Django has a [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) which seems to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not exactly meant for this purpose, an option would be to use the testing framework's [`Client`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) to fake a request to the url - be sure to use `client.login()` before making your requests, to ensure you have superuser capabilities.